# Subset dataframe based on text criteria in any column

Tags: r, regex, match

I would like to subset a R data frame based on text matching. 
I would like to reproduce in a way the behavior of the Search field in this shiny app http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html

My need is to be able to identify and store all the rows within a data frame whose content (regardless the column) matches with some text stored into a fixed vector (eg. ref <- c("match 1", "match 2", "match 3")

What is the correct way to proceed?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Regards,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, your bet is on two things:

1. Vectors
2. RegEx

such as

```
df$new_col <- df$col1[grep("text/regex", as.character(df$col1)]
```

What it does - creates new column where it writes corresponding values of col1 in which regex evaluates to TRUE.